# ftp with download progress bar is not filling c#

Tags: c#, ftp, download, progress-bar

hi people I'm trying to put a download progress bar to my ftp download program it kinda works but progress bar is not filling with the download or after download but i get the download completed message the code is below ;

```
public void yap(object o)
    {
        (o as Label).Text = "DOWNLOADING";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        ParameterizedThreadStart p = new ParameterizedThreadStart(yap);
        Thread t = new Thread(p);
        t.Start(label2);
       BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += _backgroundWorker_DoWork;
        _backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged +=
   new   ProgressChangedEventHandler(_backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
 new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();


    }

    void _backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted
 (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Download Completed");
    }

    void _backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    } 

    void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

      Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke
 (System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,new Action(delegate()
            {

                string yol = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

                FtpWebRequest FTP;
                try
                {

                    FileStream SR = new FileStream(yol + "\\list.gz", FileMode.Create);

                    FTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri
("ftp://" + textBox1.Text + "/" + "/usr/valapp/etc/list.gz"));

                    FTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

                    FTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

                    FTP.UseBinary = true;

                    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)FTP.GetResponse();

                    Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                    long cl = response.ContentLength;

                    int bufferSize = 2048;
                    int readCount;

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    while (readCount > 0)
                    {
                        SR.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    ftpStream.Close();
                    SR.Close();
                    response.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("File Downloaded!");
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
                    {
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
                }


            }));
    }

 }
 }
```

Code might be look complex but its totally works as i told only progress bar is not filling thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to update the ProgressBar after the file is actually downloaded, so I think you should look into how to get the Download-percentage while it is downloading.

Comment: So what should i do ? because i cant find any solution:/

Comment: @LarsKristensen is right. That part `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);` should be not **after** downloading, but during. You can get file size (if you can) and with the use of timer read peaces of it, when peace is read - update progress.

Comment: I get what you said but i dont know where to put those piece of code so can u tell me the exact place please

Comment: I haven't worked with FTP/ downloading in code, so I can't answer your question directly, but here's where you should start: Before downloading the file, store the size of the file in a variable, totalBytes. Then while downloading, keep track of how many bytes you have downloaded in another variable, bytesSoFar. Use this to calculate the percentage, ((bytesSoFar * 100) / totalBytes), and use  that value to call backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage);

Comment: I cant make it work like this because i cant take the downloaded bytes with ftp

Comment: You have a variable called "BufferSize" that you use when reading from your stream. I could imagine that this is the amount of bytes you read, after each iteration of the While-loop. But as I wrote, I have no experience with FTP downloading in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
            int cnt=0;
            double totalentry=response.ContentLength/bufferSize;
            while (readCount > 0)
            {

                SR.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                if(_backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress) 
                {
                    _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(cnt++*100/(int)totalentry);
                }

            }
```

You may just edit this part of the code.